# Dynamically check height of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

I want to check the height of an element every time the site changes, because of a viewport resize or a click event.

At the moment I'm using the following code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var height = document.getElementById("head").offsetHeight;

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.top = height + 'px';
    }
});
```

It's possible that the height of "head" changes. So I need to check the actual height if there are any changes at the site/viewport.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Done. Posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check on window resize

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  //check element height
});
```

Comment: that's working. But only after the click. and the height is wrong. it's correct after I click a second time

Answer (score 1):

You can use onresize event listener of javascript

```
var header= document.getElementById("head")
header.addEventListener('onresize', function(){
// do your code here
});
```

Comment: did you get event callback?

Comment: how could i check that? maybe it's because it is inside  "jQuery(function ($) { ..... });"

Comment: Please remove it from jquery function it's javascript, write globally ....And Just add alert or console.log ---->>>> header.addEventListener('onresize', function(){
alert("Listener called")
});

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = document.getElementById("head"),
    height;

function eventHandler () {

  height = element.offsetHeight;
  console.log(height);

  // rest of your code

}

window.addEventListener('resize', eventHandler)
element.addEventListener('click', eventHandler)
```

You can bind two different event listeners and pass the same function as a callback if you want to share code logic and reduce redundancy.

Comment: could you explain which of my code should be in your function?

Comment: My code is inside of jQuery "jQuery(function ($) { .....  });" Is there anything to change because of that?

Comment: All your variable caching can be done outside of `eventHandler()` as they don't change. Inside put a logic to update `.top` styling, so in your case a `for` loop and the body of that loop. So take out all `document.getElement...` outside of eventHandler, put calculating height inside `eventHandler()` and `for` loop that sets a `top` position inside

Comment: It's kind of working if I move it outside of jQuery. But it's only working AFTER a click/resize. not after I load the page. And if I click inside the header and the header size changes. the height isn't the actual height. It's the height before the click.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
$( window ).ready(function() {
    var height = document.getElementById("head").offsetHeight;

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.top = height + 'px';
    }
});

$( window ).click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var height = document.getElementById("head").offsetHeight;

        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.top = height + 'px';
        }
    }, 500);
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
    var height = document.getElementById("head").offsetHeight;

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.top = height + 'px';
    }
});
```

The timeout is for the correct height after the click and an animation.